# ListView VERY slow when images are loaded (using Universal Image Loader)

Tags: android, performance, listview, image-loading

My listView runs very smooth with just text - but as soon as I try to load in thumbnails (even from cache), it runs SOO choppy.

I'm using the [Universal Image Loader script](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

The code in my ArticleEntryAdapter within `public View getView(...)` method:

```
/**
     * PHOTOS
     */
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this.mContext)
        .enableLogging()
        .memoryCacheSize(41943040)
        .discCacheSize(104857600)
        .threadPoolSize(10)
        .build();

    DisplayImageOptions imgDisplayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        //.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .cacheInMemory() 
        .cacheOnDisc() 
        //.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACT) 
        .build();

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);

    //loads image (or hides image area)
    imageLoader.displayImage("", viewHolder.thumbView); //clears previous one
    if(article.photopath != null && article.photopath.length() != 0)
    {
        imageLoader.displayImage(
            "http://img.mysite.com/processes/resize_android.php?image=" + article.photopath + "&size=150&quality=80",
            viewHolder.thumbView,
            imgDisplayOptions
            );
        viewHolder.thumbView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder.thumbView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide image
        viewHolder.thumbView.invalidate(); //should call after changing to GONE
    }
```

Logcat shows that it's loading the images from cache (I think):

```
ImageLoader    Load image from memory cache [http://img.mysite.com/processes/...
```

I'm testing it on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus and running Android 4.0.4 (though my minSdkVersion="8")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the instantation of **ImageLoaderConfiguration config, DisplayImageOptions imgDisplayOptions, ImageLoader imageLoader** outside of your getView method as private fields/members of your Adapter class.  You should only have create these things once,  not everytime getView is called.

Edit : without seeing your whole Adapter class,  here a stab at what I'm saying. I hope its close to what you have and you can make it work out. Lemme know either way.

```
public class MyAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {
    /**
     * PHOTOS
     */
    static ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this.mContext)
        .enableLogging()
        .memoryCacheSize(41943040)
        .discCacheSize(104857600)
        .threadPoolSize(10)
        .build();

    static DisplayImageOptions imgDisplayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        //.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .cacheInMemory() 
        .cacheOnDisc() 
        //.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACT) 
        .build();

    static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    /**
     * 
     */
    public MyAdapterClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        imageLoader.init(config);           
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
     */
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //loads image (or hides image area)
        imageLoader.displayImage("", viewHolder.thumbView); //clears previous one
        if(article.photopath != null && article.photopath.length() != 0)
        {
            imageLoader.displayImage(
                "http://img.mysite.com/processes/resize_android.php?image=" + article.photopath + "&size=150&quality=80",
                viewHolder.thumbView,
                imgDisplayOptions
                );
            viewHolder.thumbView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.thumbView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide image
            viewHolder.thumbView.invalidate(); //should call after changing to GONE
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: also, if you are runnning in debug mode, it will slow down lots of stuff.

Comment: @forgivegod.. I am also facing the same problem with this.. Can u tell me how to Put the instantation of those classes. I have used it in Constror. But it is not working. Pls send me the snippet of adapter.. srikanth.gnani@gmail.com. Thank you..

Comment: I edited my answer to help you out @wolverine .  HTH helps.  sorry for the late response.  hurricane sandy and all. this my first time online for a week without a mobile browser.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but when I faced this issue, I observed that using images of smaller sizes increased the speed immensely. Earlier I was using images in upwards of 150KBs, I switched them to about 10 a piece and it worked perfectly well. Just adding to the above train of thought, might come in handy for optimizing later on.