# Universal Image Loader images with big resolution

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I using universal image loader to load images from gallery to listView and i have a problem with big images when scrolling images with bigger resolution loads slower than images with lower resolution i quess it should be like that but is there any way to load them in same speed?

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
    .cacheInMemory(false)
    .cacheOnDisk(false)
    .build();``
```

code above doesnt fix this problem.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099383/listview-very-slow-when-images-are-loaded-using-universal-image-loader

Answer (score 0):

Try to preload those images which need to be shown in the next listView's items.